# How can we configure Mongodb Simple Test Ops manager on ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb

i want to configure a  MongoDB Simple Test Ops manager on ubuntu. In MongoDb Doc, Configuration is available for RHEL6 only. is it necesssary to configure it on RHEL6?

Answer (score 1):

From doc:
"This procedure installs the test deployment on servers running either RHEL 6+ or Amazon Linux."

The steps described  in above are for RHEL 6+ and Amazon Linux. However, you can perform step 1-5 for ubuntu as usual as if you are installing mongod.

You can continue from step 6. Once you are done above steps.